# Copy a range with rows to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

My requirement is to copy rows from sheet3 having font color black to sheet1.I have a range of rows selected from sheet3 in a workbook. I want to copy this and paste in sheet1.Selection part is ok, but Error (Application defined or object defined ) in copy statement.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim lastRow, i As Long    
Dim CopyRange As Range

lastRow = Sheet3.Rows.Count

With Sheets(Sheet3.Name)

    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
         If .Rows(i).Font.Color = 0 Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
CopyRnge.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J300")    
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Option Explicit` and you will find your error immediatly

Comment: Thanks, CopyRnge instead of CopyRange.

Answer (score 0):

`Option Explicit` forces you to declare ALL the variables you use.

`CopyRnge.Copy` didn't exist when you ran the program, so Excel showed a run-time error.

[image: Run-time error 1004]

Common errors like these can be avoided by turning on `Option Explicit` by default.

**How to enable Option Explicit for all modules in VBA:**

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

**Suggested Code To Try:**

The code below uses `Option Explicit` and it also takes advantages of using Object References.

By setting up Object References, you can rely on Intellisense to ensure you avoid typos.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyBlackText()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Dim srcRangeToCopy As Range
    Dim destinationRange As Range

    Dim wrkbook As Workbook

    'Setup Object references by assigning and using the 'Set' keyword
    Set wrkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    Set destinationRange = wrkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J300")


    With wrkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

        'Using Cells(1,1).Address instead of saying Range("A1")
        lastRow = .Range(Cells(1, 1).Address).End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow

             If .Rows(i).Font.Color = 0 Then

                If srcRangeToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set srcRangeToCopy = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set srcRangeToCopy = Union(srcRangeToCopy, .Rows(i))
                End If

            End If

        Next

    End With

    srcRangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=destinationRange

End Sub
```